# Posting array of integers to asp.net web api

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I have a class like below for posting to asp.net web api

```
public class PostData
{

    public int ID { get; set; }

    public int[] SelectedChoiceIDs { get; set; }

}
```

In my ApiController there is a method called send which gets `PostData` object as parameter.

```
public bool Send(PostData data)
{


}
```

The problem is whenever I trace the method Web API is not binding to the array of integers ,that is, `SelectedChoiceIDs` property. How can i force to bind the array of integers to "`SelectedChoiceIDs`" property?

The data i'm sending is like

```
{ "ID" : 3 , "SelectedChoiceIDs" : [ 3,4,5,6 ] }
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You don't need to do anything, this will work out of the box.

If you POST the exact object you provided:

```
{ "ID" : 3 , "SelectedChoiceIDs" : [ 3,4,5,6 ] }
```

with `Content-Type: application/json`, the default model binder will automatically pick it up.

```
public class PostData
{

    public int ID { get; set; }

    public int[] SelectedChoiceIDs { get; set; }

}

public void DummyController : ApiController
{
    public void Post(PostData data)
    {
        //data here will be PostData with ID and an array of 4 integers
    }
}
```

Make sure you provide the `Content-Type`, and that you are indeed posting correct JSON, not for example:

```
{data: { "ID" : 3 , "SelectedChoiceIDs" : [ 3,4,5,6 ] } }
```

Answer (score -3):

Possible dupplicate of 
[ASP.NET MVC bind array in model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2080355/asp-net-mvc-bind-array-in-model)

[Here](http://haacked.com/archive/2008/10/23/model-binding-to-a-list.aspx) is blogpost explaining what you have to do.

Comment: that's MVC answer, and the issue here is Web API

Comment: There is ApiController in the question. Also it is tagged with "asp.net-mvc".