# Posting array to WebApi action method

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api

I am developing a WebApi endpoint for a client application. The API has a method with the following signature:

```
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Post([FromBody] int[] employeeIds)
```

The sample POST-request I use to trigger this endpoint:

```
Authorization: Bearer [token]
Host: localhost:44301
Content-Length: 16
Content-Type: application/json

[10,20,30,40,50]
```

This all works fine and dandy. The problem is that the client application can only send **key/value** pairs. As you can see from the sample POST-request, I am only sending the value of the array.

The only solution I can think of is to define a model with the array as a property, but this adds a new class to my codebase with no other purpose than being a container.

How do I overcome this problem?

---

#### Edit

I'm looking for a solution that allows the client to send the array as the value component of a key/value pair:

```
key = [10, 20, 30, 40, 50]
```

How can I transform my method into accepting such a request?

Comment: How would the problematic "client request" would look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a Dictionary like so:

```
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Post([FromBody] Dictionary<string, int> employeeIds)
```

Then you could send a request like the following

```
Authorization: Bearer [token]
Host: localhost:44301
Content-Length: 16
Content-Type: application/json

{
    'first': 10,
    'second': 20,
    'third': 30
}
```

****EDIT****

In response to your update and comment on my answer, in that there is one key per array of numbers.
You could use the .Net type [Tuple](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.tuple(v=vs.110).aspx) like this:

```
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Post([FromBody] Tuple<string, int[]> employeeIds)
```

you then access the values by code using

```
string myKey = employeeIds.Item1;
int[] theIds = employeeIds.Item2;
```

The request looks like this:

```
Authorization: Bearer [token]
Host: localhost:44301
Content-Length: 16
Content-Type: application/json

{
   Item1: 'OfficeWorkers',
   Item2: [10, 20, 30, 40, 50]
}
```

However this is obviously less declarative and the tuple is less obvious to others who use the api/modify your code in the future.

If it was up to me, I'd favour a small class (only existing in the API layer) which acts as a simple model which holds data received from the API calls - then in the WebApi code - map that to a "proper" class you are using internally.

Comment: Maybe I should be more specific. What I'm looking for is key = [10,20,30,40,50]. The value is the array.

Comment: ah ok, I was under the impression there were keys for each value!
edit coming soon.....

Answer (score 0):

> Web API supports parsing content data in a variety of ways, but it does not deal with multiple posted content values. A solution for your problem could be to create a ViewModel with a property of int[] type.

Here you can read more about this question:
[Passing array of integers to webapi Method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16374954/passing-array-of-integers-to-webapi-method)

[Posting array of integers to asp.net web api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14284244/posting-array-of-integers-to-asp-net-web-api)

In short you need create ViewModel with property of int[]

Answer (score 0):

If I think your issue right, here is my sample code:

```
public string Post([FromBody]Dictionary<string, int[]> value)
{
      return "OK";
}
```

Postman client:

[image]

Hope this helps!

[image]